# laravel collection returning object format when using where('field','!=',$value)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
   $details['series'] = $Details->where('id','!=',$id);

  it return object
```

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 607,
        "title": "title",
        "audio": null,
        "thumb_image": null,    
    }
}
```

$details['series'] = $Details->where('id','==',$id);

```
[
    {
        "id": 606,
        "title": "title",
        "audio": null,
        "thumb_image": null,  
     
      
    }
]
```

why this happen,
how to solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community please can you add more details to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are refering to what happens when the result is converted into JSON then the `where` (or any filter) retains the keys by default which when converted to a JSON string results in an object since arrays in JSON must be 0 based and not have any gaps within their keys.

You can reset the key numbering like so:

```
$details['series'] = $Details->where('id','!=',$id)->values();
```

This is like calling `array_values` on an array to achieve the same thing.

Comment: my question is why this returns array when using "==" sighn

Comment: As I explained in the answer when you do `where` it filters out the values that match the condition but retains the key. You seem to have a collection with two items. When you do `where('id','!=',$id)` you are left you the 2nd item which has an index of `1` but if you do `where('id','==',$id)` you are left with the 1st item with an index of 0. If your array starts at 0 and does not have gaps in the indexes it becomes a JSON array but if it starts at anything else or has gaps in the indexes it becomes an object

Answer (score -1):

Use a first() on your collection :

```
$details['series'] = $Details->where('id','!=',$id)->first();
```

Comment: i want to get all the items as an array,
when iam using "=" it working fine,